# Sincronizar NavBar Bootstrap 5 sin usar PHP

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap

Estoy creando una web, la cual tendrá muchas sub páginas y quiero incluir una NavBar en todas ellas, estoy trabajando con boostrap 5 y quiero saber si hay alguna forma de crear una única NavBar y insertarla en todas las páginas para no tener que actualizarlas 1 por una cada vez que hago un cambio.

No quiero utilizar PHP, quiero poder cargar mi NavBar solo utilizando JavaScript.

Dejo por aquí el código de mi NavBar:

```html
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ALCOHOLIMPIADAS</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/icono.png">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--MENU-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">
          <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="70" height="70" class="d-inline-block"> ALCOHOLIMPIADAS </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../index.html">INICIO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="../#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> JUEGOS </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="../juegos_cartas.html">JUEGOS CON CARTAS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="../juegos_nada.html">JUEGOS SIN NADA</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="../#">JUEGOS DE DADOS</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="../#">CONTACTO</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
      </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el codigo para hacer esto no es demasiado complicado, en el `head` de tu archvio, en este caso pongamos que es `index.html` tienes que introdcir el siguente código:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#header').load('header.html');
    });
</script>
```

Esta funcion se encarga de cargar el archivo `header.html` dentro de tu `ìndex.html` (ten en cuenta poner la ruta correcta dentro de la función y el nombre correcto).

Crea un archivo llamado `header.html` en el mismo directorio donde esta tu `index.html`, si no esta en el mismo directorio recuerda modificar la ruta en la función de JavaScript. Dentro del archivo `header.html` introduce el código de tu `header` sin etiquetas html ni nada, solo el código del `header`, en este caso:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">
      <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="70" height="70" class="d-inline-block"> ALCOHOLIMPIADAS </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../index.html">INICIO</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="../#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> JUEGOS </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="../juegos_cartas.html">JUEGOS CON CARTAS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="../juegos_nada.html">JUEGOS SIN NADA</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="../#">JUEGOS DE DADOS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="../#">CONTACTO</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Ahora, donde quieras cargar el `header` en este caso en el `index.html` tienes que crear un `div` con el `id="header"`, te muestro como quedaría tu página:

```html
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ALCOHOLIMPIADAS</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/icono.png">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#header').load('header.html');
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--MENU-->
  <div id="header"></div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Este código funcionará independientemente de si se esta usando BootStrap o no, pero ten en cuenta que solo funcionará cuando tu web esté colgada en un servidor, ya que por seguridad, los navegadores como Google Chrome o Firefox bloquean la carga de archivos locales.